# undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask@GLIBC_2.32' installing diesel_cli

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I'm trying to install the diesel_cli crate using `cargo install diesel_cli` however I keep getting this error:

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libpq.so: undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask@GLIBC_2.32'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


  error: aborting due to previous error

  error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v1.4.1`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installM4z849`

  Caused by:
    could not compile `diesel_cli`.
```

Every solution I've found indicates I need to pass a -pthread flag to the compiler, however all the solutions are related to c/c++ where the command is being run manually or with a make file where the flag can easily be added. Is there a way of passing this flag when running the command through cargo install?

I'm running:

- Cargo version 1.45.0
- rustc version 1.45.0
- Arch linux

The output of `ldd /usr/lib/libpq.so`:

```
/usr/lib/libpq.so: /usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/lib/libpq.so)
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd863fa000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f4723fe7000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f4723d0a000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f4723cb5000)
libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f4723c5f000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4723c3d000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4723a76000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4723a6e000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f4723988000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f4723957000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f4723951000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f4723942000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /usr/lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f472393b000)
libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f472391f000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007f472390f000)
libsasl2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.3 (0x00007f47238f1000)
/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f47240f1000)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ldd /usr/lib/libpq.so` as a code block?

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `ldd /usr/lib/libpq.so` it looked like I was missing libc, after installing gcc I was able to install diesel_cli

Comment: It seems very unlikely that you had a functioning system without libc. More likely, you triggered an upgrade that installed the required version, 2.32 (released 5 August 2020).